# Spring Security authentication cross-origin with cookies vs Authorization header

Tags: cookies, spring-boot, spring-security, vuejs2

I am using Spring Security for authentication of my REST API. The authentication is working fine and Spring Security returns a token with `Set-Cookie`. The `rememberMe` feature is turned on and the same is returned in the cookie.

When I make subsequent requests, the authentication fails unless I send the user name / password in the `Authorization` header, whereas when I test in postman it works. I see that it adds `JSESSIONID` in the cookie in the request.

Since the cookie as `Http-Only` cookie, I do not think that I can read them in my JavaScript function.

So how do I authenticate the user? I was under the assumption that if the server returns a cookie with `set-cookie`, the browser should automatically append it for each request.

Login client request:

```
context.$http.get(url, {
    headers:
    {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE',
      'Authorization': auth
    }
  }
```

Request headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin,authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:localhost:9000
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/login?redirect=%2F
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
```

Response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8080
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:13
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 18 Aug 2017 05:40:55 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Set-Cookie:remember-me=dTVTMi94dnVkQzJtYXRFYmJkR1VKZz09OjA1T1F4RXVOV0RiTEx4VFdUSVByeGc9PQ; Max-Age=86400; Expires=Sat, 19-Aug-2017 05:40:55 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=4A856E0216191E8601100B600E4A227B; Path=/; HttpOnly
Vary:Origin
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Subsequent request to get data:

```
this.$http.get(url).then(function (res) {
          this.items = res.data
        })
```

Client request:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:localhost:9000
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/Languages
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
```

Server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 18 Aug 2017 05:43:26 GMT

{timestamp: 1503038407254, status: 401, error: "Unauthorized",…}
error :
"Unauthorized"
message:"Full authentication is required to access this resource"
path:"/languages"
status:401
timestamp:1503038407254
```

Adding `withCredentials : true`:

```
GET /languages HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.16.142:12345
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:8080/languages
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4
```

Response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 21 Aug 2017 06:26:24 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin
WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Realm"
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

FYI: I use vuejs in the frontend.

Comment: Did you try this: Vue.http.options.xhr = {withCredentials: true}

Comment: Yes i did try that

Comment: Can you add the full http requests and responses? That is, include the URLs of the corresponding requests and responses.

Comment: You know the first request your browser is doing is a CORS preflight OPTIONS request, right? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests And for the browser to consider that successful, the server must return an Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header that includes 'Authorization' in its value. But the response headers in the question don’t include that, so either you’re showing the wrong response headers or the preflight’s actually failing. The question also doesn’t show the response code for that response. Are you sure it’s not also 401?

Comment: What messages exactly is your browser logging in the devtools console? Also, note that you should remove `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'` from the client-side request code. Those headers are *response* headers for servers to send. The only effect that sending them a request headers will have is to trigger a CORS preflight that will fail. The only request header you want to be sending in this case is `Authorization`

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load . Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute. I see the above error

Comment: @Sam so to fix that specific error you must configure the server you’re sending the request to include an `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` response header in its response

Comment: @sideshowbarker I got that resolved and i see the cookie in the browser but based on my discussion with newbie , even though both client and server are running on same server , since its accessing through an ip , it being considered as two different domain

Comment: @Sam To enable others here to help you, use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45740207/edit to edit/update your question and indicate what the current information is at this point. Because you’ve made changes and the information in the question is no longer accurate. And please very clearly indicate exactly what problem you’re now trying to solve. For example, what is the exact error message (if any) that you’re getting in your browser devtools console at this point? What are the exact request headers the browser is sending for each request? What are the exact response headers? Response codes?

Answer (score 7):

After carefully looking at your response/request flow, you are originating requests from port 8080 to port 9000 which trigger same-origin policy(CORS) rules. CORS requests, by default, will not send credentials/cookies as documented in the link below. To enable credentials/cookies propagation, you need to set the "withCredentials" flag in your AJAX call.

Moreover, it looks like you are using vuejs. To enable withcredentials, you need to use the setting below.

```
Vue.http.options.credentials = true;
```

[MDN - Request with credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials)

Comment: I added `Vue.http.options.xhr = {withCredentials: true}` I am still receiving 401 from the server

Comment: @Sam can you add the request payload when you use withCredentials.

Comment: @Sam are you using spring-boot, if so, which version?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load ''. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: Spring boot Version is : 1.5.6

Comment: Set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152413/discussion-between-newbie-and-sam).